# How to Access rows and columns of Vector<Mat> Images on Open cv for Android?

Tags: android, opencv, vector, rows, mat

I was going through some code on open cv using Android.Can any one show me how I am gonna access the rows and columns of a vector Mat of image?Its declared and the columns and rows are accessed as given below but i am having  errors like  and .

```
vector<Mat> images;//Vector of Mat image declared
...
int im_width = images[0].cols;//its trying to access column of images matrix
int im_height = images[0].rows;//trying to access rows of Mat images
```

If this is not the right way to access the columns and rows of a vector Image, then what is it?
When it says images[0] its trying to access the index 0 of the vector of Mat images.I am not sure if this is right or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
Mat m;
m.row(i);
m.col(i);
```

ref:
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Welcome?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=opencv_cheatsheet.pdf

edit: the following works and produces expected output. perhaps you should describe your errors?

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    vector<Mat> vectors;
    Mat img1 = imread( "C:/test/1.jpg");
    Mat img2 = imread( "C:/test/2.jpg");
    vectors.push_back(img1);
    vectors.push_back(img2);
    cout<<vectors[0].rows<<endl;
    cout<<vectors[0].cols<<endl;
    cin.ignore(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to access the rows and columns of a Cv::Mat.I am trying to access the rows and columns of a Mat saved at the 0th index of a vector which is vector<Mat> images.

Comment: That is the way(legit) i am trying to do it but I dont know why but this is showing me an error that its hasn't recognized cols and rows.                                                               P.S I am working on Android using Open cv as a native code(JNI).

Answer (score 1):

The members `rows` and `cols` tell you the number of rows and cols the matrix has. To access them, you can use `at`:

```cpp
// let's assume your image is CV_8U, so that it is accessed with unsigned char
cv::Mat m = ...;

for(int r = 0; r < m.rows; ++r)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < m.cols; ++c)
  {
    char byte = m.at<unsigned char>(r, c);
    ...
  }
}
```

You can also save some calls to `at` and access data by pointer for every row:

```cpp
// let's assume your image is CV_8U, so that it is accessed with unsigned char
cv::Mat m = ...;

for(int r = 0; r < m.rows; ++r)
{
  const unsigned char *p = m.ptr<unsigned char>();
  for(int c = 0; c < m.cols; ++c, ++p)
  {
    char byte = *p;
    ...
  }
}
```

If the matrix is continuous in memory, you can get the pointer just once:

```cpp
// let's assume your image is CV_8U, so that it is accessed with unsigned char
cv::Mat m = ...;

assert(m.isContinuous());

const unsigned char *p = m.ptr<unsigned char>();

for(int r = 0; r < m.rows; ++r)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < m.cols; ++c, ++p)
  {
    char byte = *p;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am aware of the fact that i can access the rows and columns of a Mat as theMatrix.cols and theMatrix.rows.What i want to know is what happen when Mat theMatrix becomes Vector<Mat> theMatrix, how do i access the rows and columns of theMatrix[0].

Comment: `at()` is pretty slow if you are scanning the image. If the image is **not** contiguous you can put `uchar* p = m.ptr<uchar>(r);` inside the outer loop before the start of the inner loop.

Comment: @Sisay I'n not with you. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Are you implying that cv::Mat and Vector<Mat> are identical declaration.

Comment: 'Course cv::Mat and Vector<Mat> are not identical. But theMatrix[0] is just a Mat, so if you know how to process a Mat, what's the problem.

Comment: What i am trying to do is accessing the cols and rows of images declared as vector<Mat> images.The sample code i have found on the internet is doing it like images[0].cols and images[0].rows. This is showing me an error.Yes that is an Error as far as i know because we use cols and rows field for cv::Mat not vector<Mat>.So how am i gonna access rows and columns.For eg if i declared Vector<Mat> images then how do i access the rows and columns of images[0].I hope i have cleared the air now.If there is any need for further clarification, hit me up and i will do it right away.Thanks

Comment: What i want process is not the CV::Mat theMatrix but vector<Mat> theMatrix saved at theMatrix[0].Want to get the rows and columns of theMatrix[0](index 0 of the vector theMatrix)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31483/discussion-between-sisay-and-user2151446)

Answer (score 1):

All the suggestion above are not helping so i decided to create a temp variable with Mat data type and copy the 0th index of the vector to Mat temp and access the rows and columns of temp as temp.cols and temp.rows.Thanks for trying to help me though.

Comment: I think so.Not showing error related to rows and cols.I am having an Error related to minSDKVersion(quite sure this is not related to the previous error) and i am working on that right now.

Answer (score 0):

`Mat` is already a vector of an image. So you do not need to define it as a Vector
With this `images.cols` you are getting only the number of columns or rows. If you want to access to the data in specific column and row, you should do it like this:

```
int mat_value = image.get(i, j)[0];
```

Where i and j are indexes of your column and row.

**Edit:**
Alternatively you can see how the image's column and rows number by

```
int cols = image.size().width;
int rows = image.size().height;
```

P.S. I think it well explained in OpenCV documentation.

Comment: A `Mat` is not a `vector<Mat>`. `cv::Mat` has no member `get()`. Instead of `int cols = image.size().width`, you can just write `image.cols`.

Comment: can you read the question and my answer with attention please? question has a tag **Android and not C**. The meaning of word [Alternatively](https://www.google.com/search?q=Alternatively+meaning&oq=Alternatively+meaning&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.10570j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @victorovich the lines of code in the question are actually C++ JNI code, not Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mat is already a vector of an image you don't need to define vector again. All you need to do is,

```
Mat images;
for(int j =0; j <images.rows; j++)
{
  for(int k =0; k <images.cols; k++)
  {
    cout << image.at<type>(j,k)<< endl;
  }
}
```

You can use an array if you want to store these values.